# otherwise need xsl:for-each?

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0

this is the last part of my xslt where i stuck, anyone has a suggestion what i missed?
Maybe xsl:otherwise do not need xsl:for-each or my loop is not correct?
I have tried the remove the "ancestor" from the xsl:otherwise part, but it's worked.
I have tried the xsl:variable (named cost) in the xsl:otherwise part but it's not worked too.

My xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<contracts>
    <ES_CMContract contractName="test_01">
        <productInContracts>
            <ES_CMProductInContract>
                <broadcastRights>
                    <ES_CM2BROADCASTRIGHT>
                        <broadcastRightGroup>
                            <ES_BROADCASTRIGHTGROUP>
                                <costDefinitions>
                                    <ES_CM2CostDefinition>
                                        <costGroup>
                                            <ESP_2COSTGROUP name="Distributor"/>
                                        </costGroup>
                                        <involvedParty>
                                            <ES_FIRM f_name="FREMANTLE MEDIA"/>
                                        </involvedParty>
                                    </ES_CM2CostDefinition>
                                    <ES_CM2CostDefinition>
                                        <costGroup>
                                            <ESP_2COSTGROUP name="Material Cost"/>
                                        </costGroup>
                                        <involvedParty>
                                            <ES_FIRM f_name="FREMANTLE MEDIA"/>
                                        </involvedParty>
                                    </ES_CM2CostDefinition>
                                    <ES_CM2CostDefinition>
                                        <costGroup>
                                            <ESP_2COSTGROUP name="Dubbing Cost"/>
                                        </costGroup>
                                        <involvedParty>
                                            <ES_FIRM f_name="FREMANTLE MEDIA"/>
                                        </involvedParty>
                                    </ES_CM2CostDefinition>
                                    <ES_CM2CostDefinition>
                                        <costGroup>
                                            <ESP_2COSTGROUP name="Technical Cost"/>
                                        </costGroup>
                                        <involvedParty>
                                            <ES_FIRM f_name="FREMANTLE MEDIA"/>
                                        </involvedParty>
                                    </ES_CM2CostDefinition>
                                </costDefinitions>
                            </ES_BROADCASTRIGHTGROUP>
                        </broadcastRightGroup>
                    </ES_CM2BROADCASTRIGHT>
                </broadcastRights>
            </ES_CMProductInContract>
        </productInContracts>
    </ES_CMContract>
    <ES_CMContract contractName="test_02">
        <productInContracts>
            <ES_CMProductInContract>
                <broadcastRights>
                    <ES_CM2BROADCASTRIGHT>
                        <broadcastRightGroup>
                            <ES_BROADCASTRIGHTGROUP>
                                <costDefinitions>
                                    <ES_CM2CostDefinition>
                                        <costGroup>
                                            <ESP_2COSTGROUP name="Distributor"/>
                                        </costGroup>
                                        <involvedParty>
                                            <ES_FIRM f_name="Walt Disney Co Ltd."/>
                                        </involvedParty>
                                    </ES_CM2CostDefinition>
                                    <ES_CM2CostDefinition>
                                        <costGroup>
                                            <ESP_2COSTGROUP name="Dubbing Cost"/>
                                        </costGroup>
                                        <involvedParty>
                                            <ES_FIRM f_name="GRANDVIEW"/>
                                        </involvedParty>
                                    </ES_CM2CostDefinition>
                                </costDefinitions>
                            </ES_BROADCASTRIGHTGROUP>
                        </broadcastRightGroup>
                    </ES_CM2BROADCASTRIGHT>
                </broadcastRights>
            </ES_CMProductInContract>
        </productInContracts>
    </ES_CMContract>
</contracts>
```

My XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" 
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
    xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" 
    xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" 
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    
    <xsl:template match="contracts">
    
    <xsl:processing-instruction name="mso-application">progid="Excel.Sheet"</xsl:processing-instruction>
    <Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
        <Styles>
            <Style ss:ID="header" ss:Name="Normal">
                <Font ss:FontName="Verdana" ss:Bold="1"/>
            </Style>
         </Styles>
        
        <Worksheet ss:Name="Report">
            <Table>
                <Row ss:Index="1">
                    <!-- contract name -->
                    <Cell ss:Index="1" ss:StyleID="header">
                        <Data ss:Type="String">contract name</Data>
                    </Cell>
                    <!-- Cost -->
                    <Cell ss:Index="2" ss:StyleID="header">
                        <Data ss:Type="String">Cost</Data>
                    </Cell>
                    <!-- Dubbing Supplier -->
                    <Cell ss:Index="3" ss:StyleID="header">
                        <Data ss:Type="String">Dubbing Supplier</Data>
                    </Cell>
                 </Row>
                
               <xsl:for-each select="ES_CMContract">                
                <xsl:variable name="cost" select="productInContracts/ES_CMProductInContract/broadcastRights/ES_CM2BROADCASTRIGHT/broadcastRightGroup/ES_BROADCASTRIGHTGROUP/costDefinitions/ES_CM2CostDefinition"/>             
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="productInContracts/ES_CMProductInContract/episodesInContract">
                        <xsl:for-each select="productInContracts/ES_CMProductInContract/broadcastRights/ES_CM2BROADCASTRIGHT/broadcastRightGroup/ES_BROADCASTRIGHTGROUP/costDefinitions/ES_CM2CostDefinition">  
                               <Row>
                                <Cell ss:Index="1" >
                                    <Data ss:Type="String">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="@contractName"/>
                                    </Data>
                                </Cell>
                                <Cell ss:Index="2" >
                                    <Data ss:Type="String">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="productInContracts/ES_CMProductInContract/broadcastRights/ES_CM2BROADCASTRIGHT/broadcastRightGroup/ES_BROADCASTRIGHTGROUP/costDefinitions/ES_CM2CostDefinition/costGroup/ESP_2COSTGROUP/@name"/>
                                    </Data>
                                </Cell>                         
                                <Cell ss:Index="3" >
                                    <Data ss:Type="String">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="productInContracts/ES_CMProductInContract/broadcastRights/ES_CM2BROADCASTRIGHT/broadcastRightGroup/ES_BROADCASTRIGHTGROUP/costDefinitions/ES_CM2CostDefinition/involvedParty/ES_FIRM/@f_name"/>
                                    </Data>
                                </Cell>
                            </Row>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:for-each select="productInContracts/ES_CMProductInContract/broadcastRights/ES_CM2BROADCASTRIGHT/broadcastRightGroup/ES_BROADCASTRIGHTGROUP/costDefinitions/ES_CM2CostDefinition">
                        <Row>
                            <Cell ss:Index="1" >
                                <Data ss:Type="String">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::ES_CMContract/@contractName"/>
                                </Data>
                            </Cell>
                            <Cell ss:Index="2" >
                                <Data ss:Type="String">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::ES_CMContract/productInContracts/ES_CMProductInContract/broadcastRights/ES_CM2BROADCASTRIGHT/broadcastRightGroup/ES_BROADCASTRIGHTGROUP/costDefinitions/ES_CM2CostDefinition/costGroup/ESP_2COSTGROUP/@name"/>
                                </Data>
                            </Cell>
                            <Cell ss:Index="3" >
                                <Data ss:Type="String">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::ES_CMContract/productInContracts/ES_CMProductInContract/broadcastRights/ES_CM2BROADCASTRIGHT/broadcastRightGroup/ES_BROADCASTRIGHTGROUP/costDefinitions/ES_CM2CostDefinition/involvedParty/ES_FIRM/@f_name"/>
                                </Data>
                            </Cell>
                        </Row>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </Table>
          </Worksheet>
        </Workbook>
      </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8lka.jpg)

And what i want:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Krh74.jpg)

harder part:
how can i separate the costgrp like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hckyB.jpg)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expressions in an `xsl:for-each` work relative to the context node set by it.
So simply change the

```
<xsl:value-of select="productInContracts/ES_CMProductInContract/broadcastRights/ES_CM2BROADCASTRIGHT/broadcastRightGroup/ES_BROADCASTRIGHTGROUP/costDefinitions/ES_CM2CostDefinition/costGroup/ESP_2COSTGROUP/@name"/>
```

to

```
<xsl:value-of select="costGroup/ESP_2COSTGROUP/@name"/>
```

in both `<Cell ss:Index="2" >...` cases.
Now you should get the desired output.

---

However, in the above example, the

```
<xsl:when test="productInContracts/ES_CMProductInContract/episodesInContract">
```

is never reached. So it may not be necessary.

Comment: After this answer the question was updated making it too broad.

Comment: thank you, it's working fine. Could you help pls with the "harder part: how can i separate the costgrp like this:" part?

Comment: ah, i see, i will put this code in toher new question, thank you